# Throwing Exception When Saving To Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm having problems when saving text to an SQL database, the save() method.
This is the error message i'm getting.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

Heres my code, I was wondering what is the issue.Any suggestions on how to fix this? I would be grateful!

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void accountDetailsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.accountDetailsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.AccountDetails' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.accountDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.AccountDetails);
}

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Amount = decimal.Parse(amount_InvestedTextBox.Text);
    WeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(WeekIntTextBox.Text);
    TwoWeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(TWeekIntTextBox.Text);
    MonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(MonthIntTextBox.Text);
    ThreeMonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(ThreeMonthIntTextBox.Text);
    Save();
    Change();
}

private void Save()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::WindowsFormsApplication13.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
    string sql = "INSERT INTO AccountDetails (Amount Invested) values('" + amount_InvestedTextBox + ")";
    SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cn.Open();
    exesql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.accountDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.AccountDetails);
    cn.Close();
}

private void Change()
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show(this);
    Hide();
}
```

config file

```
 <configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WindowsFormsApplication13.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
        providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your connection string, which you can find in the config file.

Comment: Can you read or save any other data on this connection? Is it just this field?

Comment: post the value of  global::WindowsFormsApplication13.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, It says the config is not declared, have updated main question with config file

Comment: you are not connected to your database. check whether your sql server service is running or not. if not then start it and then try.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a SqlConnection at all?  You have a typed DataSet so all interaction with the database should be via table adapters.  If you want to insert a record into a table then use the table adapter that corresponds to that table.

The immediate cause of the issue is that you are using a SqlConnection, which is only for SQL Server, with a connection string that is for SQL Server CE.  Despite the names, SQL Server and SQL Server CE are quite different and there is a separate ADO.NET provider for each.  You don't need to worry about that at all though because, as I said, you should be using your table adapters and they incorporate all the connection, data adapter and command objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your connection string. Check your server name and Instance name in the connection string. [Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details